# Silverlight Data Validation on Custom Client-Side Class

Tags: silverlight

I have a simple viewmodel class with two properties: sEmailAddress and sEmailCompare.
I have a simple view (window) with two text boxes. The data context is set to an instance of the viewmodel. The two text boxes are bound to the two properties on the viewmodel, with the validation properties set, as follows:

```
Text="{Binding sEmailAddress,
                            Mode=TwoWay,
                            NotifyOnValidationError=True,
                            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                            ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,
                            ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"
```

My viewmodel has a Validate method as follows:

```
    Public Function Validate() As Boolean
        If Validator.TryValidateObject(Me, New ValidationContext(Me), New List(Of ValidationResult), True) Then
            Return True
        Else
            Validator.ValidateObject(Me, New ValidationContext(Me), True)
            Return False
        End If
    End Function
```

And Data Annotated properties:

```
Private _sEmailAddress As String
<Required>
Public Property sEmailAddress As String
    Get
        Return _sEmailAddress
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        If _sEmailAddress <> value Then
            _sEmailAddress = value
            OnPropertyChanged("sEmailAddress")
        End If
    End Set
End Property

Private _sEmailAddressConfirm As String
<Required>
<CustomValidation(GetType(MatchingEmailValidator), "ValidateEmail")>
Public Property sEmailAddressConfirm As String
    Get
        Return _sEmailAddressConfirm
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        If _sEmailAddressConfirm <> value Then
            _sEmailAddressConfirm = value
            OnPropertyChanged("sEmailAddressConfirm")
        End If
    End Set
End Property
```

The actual validation part is working correctly- if I leave a field blank or if the two field values do not match, then TryValidateObject returns false. But the UI does not change. So I try calling ValidateObject, and that throws a validation exception, as it should, but I don't know how to handle that exception so that the UI is updated and the textbox is outlined in red as normal.

Can anyone shed some light on what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this kind of validation in Silverlight.  The first is to throw an exception inside the property setter -- since you have `ValidatesOnExceptions`=true, that should cause the validation error to appear on the UI.  To implement this, you would basically just need to call `ValidateObject` inside the setter.

The other way, which is useful for more advanced scenarios (ie, when there may be validation rules depending on multiple properties), is to have your view-model implement [`INotifyDataErrorInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  This interface has a collection of errors that you maintain, and an event `ErrorsChanged` that you need to call when an error is added or removed.

Comment: Thank you for your response. So, it would seem that calling the ValidateObject method in my Validate method is what I am doing wrong. When I move the ValidateObject method to the setter, it does work correctly- the UI gets the standard validation treatment. I should probably use ValidateProperty instead of ValidateObject if I am doing it in the setter, right?

Comment: @Josh yes, that makes more sense.